# No reconoce comando ng

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

He instalado angular-cli y aun así no me funciona este comando, que puede ser o como lo puedo agregar.

[image: Aqui se ve quela version de angular-cli y se valida que esta instalado]
[image: Esto es lo que aparece al ejecutar el comando]

Comment: Buenas, te podría preguntar que comando usaste para instalar angular/cli?

Comment: npm install -g angular-cli

Comment: Yo he tenido este mismo problema y puedes realizar lo que comenta el compañero EDWARD o reniciar el PC como hice yo para solucionarlo. Por cierto mi sistema operativo es un W10 64-bit.

Comment: les cuento que yo tuve el mismo problema desde el terminal de win, pero probé con win powershell y si me funcionó el comando ng. Slds

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Al parecer te falta configurar las variables de entorno, debería ser la ruta

```
C:\Users\TuUsuario\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Y también

```
angular-cli\bin
```

Prueba una vez que hayas configurado estas variables reiniciar tu equipo.

Si ya tienes todo esto configurado intenta correr

```
npm run ng serve
```

**Edicion**

Para configurar tus variables de entorno debes en el buscador de windows escribir Variables de entorno :

- Seleccionar "Editar variables de entorno para esta cuenta"
- Buscar `Path`
- Y agregar, SIN ESPACIOS la ruta de tu `npm` y de tu `angular-cli` generalmente se encuentran así : `C:\Users\T015014\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin;`

Comment: ok, gracias por tu respuesta

pero no se me puedas ayudar especificando esas variables

Comment: No te entendi bien, que necesitas no sabes configurar las variables?

Comment: correcto, no se como configurar las variables

esto es lo que contiene el npm:          

#!/bin/sh

basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")


case `uname` in

    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;

esac


if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then

  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "$@"

  ret=$?

else 

  node  "$basedir/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "$@"

  ret=$?

fi

exit $ret

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta @EDWARDFABIANTAPIEROGOMEZ

Comment: Solo necesitas configurar en la variables de entono la ruta a 'ng.cmd' que se encuentra en '%AppData%\Roaming\npm'. Adicional a esto al parecer powershell no tiene permisos para ejecutar el script de angular, para remover el bloqueo ejecuta powershell como administrador y ejecuta 'Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'. Una vez realizados los  2 pasos anteriores podras ejecutar angular en consola.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando laragon el **path** que se usa en **variables de usuario** es el siguiente, por si no te corre en visual studio code

La version cambia dependiendo cual uses **node-v14.15.3-win-x64**

```
C:\laragon\bin\nodejs\node-v14.15.3-win-x64\node_modules\npm
```