# Problema al crear proyecto angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, npm

Quiero crear un proyecto en angular con ng new nombreproyecto   y me dice esto:

```
ng : El término 'ng' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si 
escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.  
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ ng new project
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Ya tengo los npm y el node.js

Probé instalar de nuevo el node y segui los pasos de la documentación en angular.io

Comment: Parece como si no hubieras instalado Angular, intenta ejecutar nuevamente `npm intall -g @angular/cli`

Comment: Una vez hecho lo anterior ejecuta `ng version` debería mostrarte la versión de Angular que instalaste.

Comment: instale y tengo la 16.11

Comment: Verifica si [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72773/no-reconoce-comando-ng) te ayuda. ;)